# Dielectrics and capacitors

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

Does the electric field after passing through the dielectric reduce. What I mean is
If there is a dielectric which is in between the plates ( but NOT IN contact with them ) 
Suppose field begins from the positive side, then passes through the dielectric ( where the field intensity reduces ) and when it makes it way out on the “other side” ( towards the negative ) , would its intensity be the same as what it was inside the dielectric or same as what it was before it encountered the dielectric ?

Answer (score 0):

A dielectric is a nonconducting, polarisable material. This means that, when an electric field is applied to it, the molecules and atoms which comprise it shift to align with the electric field. This creates another electric field which partially cancels the original one, thus reducing the overall electric field, inside and outside of the dielectric, so the intensity would be lower than without the dielectric.

Comment: Cool but what I want to know is.. after the field makes its way out of the dielectric, that from medium of dielectric to medium outside, would its field strength remain the same as it was in the dielectric or be the same as vacuum field ?

Comment: @user208400 Electric fields decay as an inverse square of distance, so the component from the dielectric is smaller outside of it. However, the component from the charge also decreases with distance from it. In the case of a parallel plate capacitor, where we assume uniform electric field due to the charges, then the electric field should be larger outside of the dielectric.